# Recursively remove square brackets and their surrounded contents from file name

Tags: bash, regular-expression, rename

I am trying recursively remove parenthesis and it's contents (`[.*]`), if it is at the beginning of the file name.

For example, `[Author1]BookName.epub` should be renamed to `BookName.epub`.

But when parenthesis is not at the beginning (ex. `BookName[Author1].epub` ) nothing should change.

This command works `find . -type f -exec rename -v "s/\[.*\]//g" '{}' \;`

But when I add `^` to make sure the parenthesis is at the beginning of the file name (`find . -type f -exec rename -v "s/^\[.*\]//g" '{}' \;`), it does not work. By does not work i mean, the command runs successfully but the file names are not changed. No error, no message.

What might be the issue here?

Comment: `find . -type f -exec rename -v "s/^\[.*\]//g" '{}' \;` command runs successfully but the file names are not changed. No error, no message.

Comment: @roaima edited the question.

Comment: By default, the Perl `rename` command applies the given expression to the whole pathname (which doesn't start with `[`). See if yours has the `--filename` or equivalent option.

Comment: The `rename` utility will not rename files if it creates a name collision. Is that what's happening for you?

Comment: @steeldriver Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what's happening here you should use the `-print` action (and temporarily stop `rename` from trying to change anything by using the `-n` flag):

```
find . -type f -print -exec rename -n 's/^\[.*\]//g' {} \;
```

Look at the file names emitted from the command. None will match your pattern because they all start with `./`.

Instead you need to match `[ … ]` immediately after the last `/` of the line. This simpler version assumes there is no match to `/[ … ]` in a directory component:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n 's!(.*/)\[.*?]!$1!s' {} +
```

This more complex version handles the possibility correctly (and is quite accepting of the simpler scenario too):

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n 's!(.*/)\[[^/]*?]([^/]*)$!$1$2!s' {} +
```

RE breakdown:

- `s!x!y!s` - Match RE `x` and substitute with text `y`. The trailing `s` allows a match to continue across multiple lines
- `(.*/)` - Match as much as possible up to and including a `/`. Call this first grouped match `$1`
- `\[` - Match a literal `[`
- `.*?]` - Match as little as possible up to and including `]`
- `([^/]*)` - Match as much as possible provided it's not `/`. Call this match `$2`
- `$` - Match "*end of line*"
- `$1$2` - Replace everything we've matched with the groups `$1` and `$2`

In either case change the `-n` back to `-v` only when you are sure it's doing what you want.

Comment: Why it gives error `Can't rename ... No such file or directory` for command such as `find . -type f -exec rename -v 's!(.*/)_!$1!s' '{}' +`, to remove `_` from the beginning of file name.

Comment: Use the diagnosis approach I give in the first sentence of my answer: (1) use `-printf` to see what's going on, (2) stop using `rename -v` and instead use `rename -n` until you know it really works

Comment: That regex doesn't actually make sure it's the last `/` of the filename, it could match `./[foo]bar/whatever` and try to rename it to `./bar/whatever`. Not that it probably comes up... Something like `rename -n 's!(.*/)\[.*?]([^/]*)$!$1$2!s' {} +` or `rename -n 's!([^/]*/)*+\[.*?]!$1!s' {} +` might work to prevent that

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes though the `\[.*?\]` would also need to be changed to `\[[^/]*?\]` like in my answer.

Comment: RE fixed. I think

Answer (score 4):

When renaming files, you want to make sure you change only the name of the files (the last component of the path)

With some variants of perl rename, that can be done with the `-d` option.

```
find . -depth -name '*\[*\]*' -type f -exec rename -v -d 's/^\[.*?\]//s' {} +
```

See also the non-greedy variant of `.*`: `.*?` so `./foo[x]bar/[a]b[c]d` becomes `./foo[x]bar/b[c]d` instead of `./foo[x]bar/d` (with `\[.*\]` matching `[a]b[c]`), and the `s` flag so `.` also matches on newline characters as we're dealing with file paths here, not lines of text.

The `-depth` (so files are renamed before the directories they're in) is not strictly necessary here as you're only renaming regular files, but it's a good idea to remember to take the habit to including it when renaming files as it's often necessary.

If your `rename` doesn't support the `-d` option, you can do it with:

```
find . -depth -name '*\[*\]*' -type f -exec rename '
  s:(?<!/)\[[^/]*?\](?=[^/]*\z)::s' {} +
```

That is remove the `[<characters-other-than-slash>]` provided they follow a `/` and provided they're followed by only non-slash characters up to the end of the path (`\z`).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is comfortable with [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) and [rnr](https://github.com/ismaelgv/rnr), the command is:

```
fd -t f -x rnr -f --no-dump '\[.*\]' ''
```

Not using `-f` is like using `--dry-run`. `--dry-run` is default.

If you do not use `--no-dump` and have the dump file then you can even [undo the rename operation](https://github.com/ismaelgv/rnr#undoredo-operations-using-dump-file).